# Perl s/$array[1]\b/$array[1] won't replace

Tags: perl

I would like to replace the string $array[1] by the actual variable value.
the \b doesn't seem to work 
Does anyone know how the replace the array variable ? What's the delimiter ?

s/$array[1]\b/$array[1]

Comment: like `s/\$array\[1\]/$array[1]/` ... ? (escape special characters)

Answer (score 2):

The `[ ... ]` has a special meaning in regular expressions (it defines a "character class"). If you want to use `[` to mean a `[`, then you need to escape it with a `\`.

```
s/\$array\[1]/$array[1]/
```

**Update:** Added escape to `$`. Removed `\b`.

Comment: Do you mean :
s/$array \ [1 \ ]\b/$array[1]/ ?

What about the second part ?

Comment: @FaroukH: I mean what I wrote. The closing `]` can't be a special character if you've escaped the opening `[`. And the second half of the expression isn't a regular expression so there's no need to escape anything.

Comment: What about the `$`?

Comment: And the `\b` should probably be dropped. It effectively means `(?=\w)` here, which doesn't seen intended.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a real templating engine to perform such a substitution, this will allow you to extend it to things that don't look exactly like `$array[1]` without making it more complicated, but you will need to alter your input to what the templating engine expects. One option is [Text::Template](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Template).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::Template 'fill_in_string';

my $input = 'foo {$array[1]} bar';
my @array = 1..10;
my $rendered = fill_in_string $input, HASH => {array => \@array};
print $rendered, "\n"; # foo 2 bar
```